# The variable is returning empty in my Python script

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml, vertex-ai-pipeline

I am working on a Python script and using GCP Cloud Build to run it. Instead of hardcoding some of the variables, I am trying to use a Cloud Build YAML file to define the variables there and then use them in my Python script. However, it keeps returning an empty string. Can you review the code and let me know why?

yaml file

```
 steps
    args:
  - 'python3'
  - 'test.py'
  - '--project=${_PROJECT_ID}'
  - '--dataset=${_DATASET_ID}'
  - '--table=${_TABLE_NAME}'

substitutions:
_PROJECT_ID: 'test1det'
_DATASET_ID: 'testdataset'
_TABLE_NAME: 'testtable'
```

python code test.py

```
def tst(
    project_id: str=os.getenv('_PROJECT_ID', 'default_project_id'),
    dataset_id: str=os.getenv('_DATASET_ID', 'default_dataset_id'),
    table_name: str=os.getenv('_TABLE_NAME', 'default_table_name')
):
```

Comment: You're sending the parameters as command line arguments, which are in `sys.argv`, not as environment variables. You can use the `argparse` module to parse arguments.

Comment: It's not env var but program argument.

Comment: @Barmar didn't understand it, can you provide an example or let me know what to fix in my code

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere what you mean, the cloud build document is showing to define it that way

Comment: Search the Internet for articles/documentation on how to use **program arguments** and **environment variables**. Your code is using environment variables, but your YAML is using program arguments.

Comment: @JohnHanley even if i change it to this, still same issue - project_id: str=$_PROJECT_ID

Comment: `$_PROJECT_ID is a variable. You must read the program arguments and set that variable.